# regex in Mysql select statement

Tags: mysql, regex, performance

I need to search for some user input patterns in database.
is it efficient to use Regex in Mysql `SELECT` statement's where clause ( in a scale of 10000 rows on an indexed column)?
My search is for dates and can be in these three forms :

- `2012` that should match `2012` , `2012/*` & `2012/*/*`
- `2012/10` that should match `2012/10` & `2012/10/*`
- `2012/10/3` that should match only `2012/10/3`

Note: I have three columns that should be checked for this type of match separately.

Comment: Are your fields always valid dates or do they need to be validated? Ie would it be possible for a column to contain `2012isagoodyear` and need to reject it?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: yes, they're always valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I can't find a definite reference in the MySQL documentation, due to the index structure, regex matches *can not use index lookups*.

They may scan indexes using the regex instead of scanning the full table, but any regex search will be more or less equivalent to a full table scan.

If your regex starts with a constant string, you may want to structure the query as;

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE field LIKE 'tr%' AND field RLIKE 'tr[uae].*'
```

to get some index help from the LIKE that - if matched from the start of the string - can use the index to its advantage.

EDIT: Since your selects are fairly simple and match from the start of the string, you can just use LIKE to make them work, which *will utilize indexes* well;

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE field1='2012' OR field1 LIKE '2012/%'
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE field1='2012/10' OR field1 LIKE '2012/10/%'
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE field1='2012/10/3'
```

The reason to split the comparison into two is to avoid a search for `2012/1` that would match `2012/10` with just a LIKE that covers both cases (ie `LIKE '2012/1%'`).

Answer (score 0):

That happens because of LIKE is not supposed to accept regular expression as a parameter. There is [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) for such things

```
WHERE field NOT REGEXP '%_[0-9]+'
```